# Render XHTML Content with parameter carried by URL

Tags: jsf, xhtml

My problem is described in the following:
I'm building a jsf/xhtml application with JavaBeans. I have a page called "event.xhtml" and it's function should be to show detailed information for an event. Obviously there will be more than one event in the application (or in the database) which i'ld like to display on this page. My idea was to hand over some like ID of the event (unique key) that i can pull the information from the event where the ID is the same as in the database. The question is how can i hand over the ID from, for example, a page called "eventOverview.xhtml" to "event.xhtml" that i can call a function in "event.xhtml" like findByID(ID id) => Event event.

Conclusion: ID is on "eventOverview.xhtml" and should be given to "event.xhtml".

Regards,
Ralf Meier

Comment: .. and there are many other possibilities / duplicates. https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+jsf+pass+parameter+page

Comment: Thank you i didnt found it yet before